# Cannot upload Cloudinary image Node.js

Tags: url, meteor, file-upload, upload, cloudinary

I am trying to upload image to cloudinary through url. I have tried the following code:

```js
        var new_url = $.cloudinary.url(currentPostId+"_front_image.jpg");
        console.log(new_url);
        console.log("check_first");
        Cloudinary.upload(new_url, {public_id: postProperties._id+"_front_image"}, function(err, res) {
          console.log(err);
          console.log("Upload Result: " + res);
          console.log("check_second");
        });
        console.log("check_third");
```

I am sure the new_url is valid cause I can open it and see the image. I made two console.log but I found that I can get "**check_first**" and "**check_third**" but not "**check_second**". It seems that the **Cloudinary.upload** funtion doesn't work (I also tried **cloudinary.uploader.upload()** but still failed) and there is no error message on my console. I have no idea what happened. I really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending a Cloudinary URL (i.e., `http://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/image/upload/<image_name>` to the uploader. The upload won't work because there is no such file.

Try to pass the image itself to the uploader (either from a local path or from a remote location, any `http` or `https` URL).

Then, the upload call should be -

```
cld.uploader.upload('<image>',function(res){console.log(res);},{public_id:"<public_id>"})
```

For more info on Cloudinary data upload options - 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#data_upload_options